# How do I fix "unknown command" in TtH?

Tags: html

I have to convert LaTeX to HTML by TtH, but TtH can't recognize some commands like "/triangle", how do I let TtH convert these unknown commands? Thanks!

Comment: tth is very old and probably unsupported, why not use a supported system such as tex4ht or latexml?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because I must use it in very old software. I've tested other choices and didn't work well except TtH.

Comment: The C code is at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/tth/dist  I guess you just need to copy the entries for a similar command and duplicate for `\triangle` (which you have written as `/triangle` above.)

Answer (score 1):

T<sub>T</sub>H supports custom definitions inside the `.tex` file and it supports Unicode through html entities. So for `\triangle` you can use the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\triangle{△}
\begin{document}
abc

$x = \sqrt{2 + \diamond} \cdot \triangle$
\end{document}
```

`$ tth -u testfile.tex` (note the `-u` to use html entities)

Result:

[image]

Note however that the generated HTML is a bit messy, see below. However, both Firefox and Chrome seem to understand it.

```html
<html>
[some details omitted]
 
<title>abc</title>

abc

<div class="p"><!----></div>
x = &#8730;{2 + &#9674;} &#183;â³
<br /><br />
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my life!